# Rake task failing to load :environment properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I'm running a custom rake task...

```
namespace :import do

  desc "Import terms of service as HTML from stdin"
  task :terms => :environment do
    html = STDIN.read
    settings = ApplicationWideSetting.first
    settings.terms_and_conditions = html
    if settings.save
      puts "Updated terms of service"
    else
      puts "There was an error updating terms of service"
    end
  end

end
```

The model ApplicationWideSetting is reported as undefined when running the task in the  `production` environment. However, when running the task on other environments (ie. `development`, `staging`, `test`.)  the task runs fine.

Running the process in rails console, in all environments, completes ok.

Does anyone know what's going on, things I could check?

**note**: I ran the task with

```
puts Rails.env
```

To check the shell environment var RAILS_ENV was getting set/read correctly. I've also tried both with and without the square brackets around the :environment dependency declaration.

**additional info:** Rails v3.2.14

**further info**: I've setup a completely fresh rails app, and the script works fine in any environment. Since the install in question is a real production environment, I'll have to setup another deploy and check it thoroughly. More info as I find it.

Comment: rake import:terms RAILS_ENV=production??

Comment: I've exported RAILS_ENV= production and puts it to stdout to ensure its set. I'll give that a try anyway, but it'd be very odd if it works...

Comment: @beck03076 predictably that had no effect.

Comment: What happens if you remove the brackets from environment? I typically only see it as `task :terms => :environment`.

Comment: @d_ethier - I added the bracketing in a desperate attempt to try and fix it! this was happening originally with the standard generated :environment dependency.  As this is only failing under the production environment, and the shell environment var is successfully set, I guess there's something in the config of production that's causing the fault... Problem is, I don't know what the culprit might be since it runs fine as server and console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a nutshell, Rails doesn't eager load models (or anything else) when running rake tasks on Production.

The simplest way to work with a model is to `require` it when you begin the rake task, and it should work as expected, in this case:

```
# explicitly require model
require 'application_wide_setting'
```

It's possible to eager load the entire rails app with:

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```

However, you may have issues with some initializers (ie. devise)

Comment: Thank you so much. This also helps e.g. when you want to access different STI models using the base class.