# Cannot load namespaced model when invoking rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rake-task

I got a rake task which invokes other rake tasks, so my development data can be easily reset.

the first rake task (lib/tasks/populate.rake)

```
# Rake task to populate development database with test data
# Run it with "rake db:populate"
namespace :db do
  desc 'Erase and fill database'
  task populate: :environment do
    ...
    Rake::Task['test_data:create_company_plans'].invoke
    Rake::Task['test_data:create_companies'].invoke
    Rake::Task['test_data:create_users'].invoke
   ...
  end
end
```

the second rake task (lib/tasks/populate_sub_scripts/create_company_plans.rake)

```
namespace :test_data do
  desc 'Create Company Plans'
  task create_company_plans: :environment do
    Company::ProfilePlan.create!(name: 'Basic', trial_period_days: 30, price_monthly_cents: 4000)
    Company::ProfilePlan.create!(name: 'Professional', trial_period_days: 30, price_monthly_cents: 27_500)
    Company::ProfilePlan.create!(name: 'Enterprise', trial_period_days: 30, price_monthly_cents: 78_500)
  end
end
```

when I run bin/rake db:populate then i get this error

> rake aborted! LoadError: Unable to autoload constant
>   Company::ProfilePlan, expected
>   /home/.../app/models/company/profile_plan.rb to define it

but when I run the second rake task independently it works well.

The model (path: /home/.../app/models/company/profile_plan.rb)

```
class Company::ProfilePlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  # == Constants ============================================================

  # == Attributes ===========================================================

  # == Extensions ===========================================================
  monetize :price_monthly_cents

  # == Relationships ========================================================
  has_many :profile_subscriptions

  # == Validations ==========================================================

  # == Scopes ===============================================================

  # == Callbacks ============================================================

  # == Class Methods ========================================================

  # == Instance Methods =====================================================
end
```

Rails 5.0.1
Ruby 2.4.0

The App was just upgraded from 4.2 to 5

**It works when I require the whole path:**

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/company/profile_plan.rb"
```

But this seems strange to me, because in the error message rails has the correct path to the Model. Does someone know why I have to require the file when invoked from another rake task?

Thank you very much

Comment: But you have `/home/.../app/models/company/profile_plan.rb` right?

Comment: @MikDiet, thank you. yes, I added them to my question

Comment: Try to define company module `module Company class ProfilePlan < ...`

Comment: @taro, thank you for your idea, I also tried this before, but I get: 
TypeError: Company is not a module
I think this is because I also have a model named Company

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that rake doesn't eager load, so when you call the `create_company_plans.rake` alone it loads the referred objects, however when you invoke it from another rake, it doesn't know you will need them and so they are not loaded.

You can take a look at this other [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18583814/7219974) which was similar to yours.

I think maybe you don't need to require the whole path, just:

```
require 'models/company/profile_plan'
```

Comment: require 'profile_plan' returns LoadError: cannot load such file -- profile_plan

Comment: what if you `require 'company'`?

Comment: I get 
rake aborted! LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Company::ProfilePlan, expected /home/.../app/models/company/profile_plan.rb to define it

Comment: Yes, look at my question, I updated it. require the file with the whole path works. But I am not sure why this error happened at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation :)

Comment: if you require each file you reference, that can get repetitive. probably better would be to refactor the rake stuff into your main codebase, and call those methods from the task.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you can probably overcome the problem by `reenable` ing and then `revoke` ing the task as given below. Pardon me if this doesn't work.

```
['test_data:create_company_plans', 'test_data:create_companies'].each do |task|
  Rake::Task[task].reenable
  Rake::Task[task].invoke
end
```

There is more info on this stackoverflow question [how-to-run-rake-tasks-from-within-rake-tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577944/how-to-run-rake-tasks-from-within-rake-tasks) .